# GetRawInputBuffer(..) limitations when it is running outside an MFC message pump

Tags: c#, c++, windows-7-x64, raw-input

Does the Windows 7 C library function GetRawInputBuffer(..) have any limitations when it is running in C or C++ function XYZ which is not the MFC windows procedure for customizing the response to events within my Windows 7 64 bit computer and operating system?

Specifically, I observed that when I am requesting a HID report such as rawdata.data.hid[2]/16 for measuring the clicked state of CH Products VM Desktop joystick's button 27 that there is randomness in the output result even when I am not pressing the buttons but exercising  the joystick yoke.

Also, I am invoking the extern "C" declspec(dllexport) function from a C# WinForm program's default Windows Message function.

```
RAWINPUT *raw;
status = GetRawInputBuffer(0,&size,sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
assert(status == 0);
raw = new RAWINPUT [sizeof(RAWINPUT)*size];
UINT count = GetRawInputBuffer(raw,&size,sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
```

Please comment on

1) whether  the above might fix my randomness problem

2) how we can workaround this randomness problem.

Comment: What type of randomess are you observing?

Comment: @Ben, The randomness I observed is that the byte corresponding to button 27, data[2] - round(data[2]/16)* 16 jumps all over the place in between consecutive button 27 presses as well as when I am not touching any buttons. Here is the URL I patterned my code after, http://www.gamedev.net/blog/1750/entry-2259016-raw-input-api/. Please look at JD_Rushing's function void Gamepad::StateChange. Thank you.

Comment: I think you want `data[2] & 0x10`. Round is not the correct function here.

Comment: Also I suggest you use the DirectInput API rather than the Raw Input API.

Comment: @Ben, Thank you for your idea. May I ask why I should use data[2] - data[2] & 0x10 for button 27 of the CH Products VM desktop joystick? Thank you.

Comment: I am not familiar with the product, but it appears you are trying to test individual bits. This is done using the bitwise operators. Now, it looks like I misread this and it should be `data[2] & 0x0f` (bottom four bits of byte 2) which you want.

Comment: @Ben Don't do that. Please. Even Microsoft considers DirectInput deprecated. It is just a wrapper for Raw Input, so why add such unnecessary overhead?

Comment: @Ben, Please tell me the complete formula for determining whether button 27 has been pressed with respect to data[2]. Thank you

Comment: @LHLaurini, Am I using the right approach for finding out whether button 27 was just pressed:                                                                                                                    BYTE b = Point.data.hid.bRawData[2] & 0xf;
  BYTE c = Point.data.hid.bRawData[2] - b * 16;
  if (c >= 8){
   printf("No Button 27 Pressed\n");
  }
  else if (c == 1 || c == 4) {
   printf("Button 27 Pressed\n");
  }

Comment: @Ben, Please let me know if I am using the right formula shown next:BYTE b = Point.data.hid.bRawData[2] & 0xf;
  BYTE c = Point.data.hid.bRawData[2] - b * 16;
  if (c >= 8){
   printf("No Button 27 Pressed\n");
  }
  else{
   printf("Button 27 Pressed\n");
  } Thank you again.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know the answer - it depends on the particular joystick.

Comment: @Ben, May I ask additional questions in the next few days about the bit operations underlying the buffer data returned by reference from GetRawInputBuffer? Thank you.

Comment: @Ben, When I leave button 27 untouched , I get the following stream of bytes values for bRawData[2], Oxfc , Ox17, Ox17, 0x1a, Ox0, 0xf9, 0x09 some of which I calculate as button 27 pressed, 0x17, 0x0, 0x22. Is there any other bit math we need to do to process the  null hypothesis? Thank you.